# Ignoring all implemented interface properties in EF CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Not so long ago I used DataBase First approach with edmx models. I've created partial classes to extend functionality of Domain Models generated by edmx.

```
//Generated by tt in edmx
public partial class DomainObject
{
    public int PropertyA {get; set;}
    public int PropertyB {get; set;}
}

//My own partial that extends functionality on generated one       
public partial class DomainObject: IDomainEntity
{
    public int EntityId {get; set;}
    public int EntityTypeId {get; set;}
    public int DoSomethingWithCurrentEntity()
    {
        //do some cool stuff
        return 0;
    }
}
```

All partials were implementing interface **IDomainEntity**

```
public interface IDomainEntity
{
    int EntityId {get; set;}
    int EntityTypeId {get; set;}
    int DoSomethingWithCurrentEntity();

    //Another huge amount of properties and functions
}
```

So all properties from this interface were not mapped to tables in DataBase

Now I've migrate to Code First approach and all this properties are trying to map to DataBase. Of course I could use [NotMapped] attribute but amount of properties in interface and classes is huge (more than 300) and continuing to grow further. Is there any approach to ignore all properties from partial or interface for all classes at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection to find out which properties to ignore, then ignore them with Fluent API in `DbContext.OnModelCreating` method:

```
foreach(var property in typeof(IDomainEntity).GetProperties())
    modelBuilder.Types().Configure(m => m.Ignore(property.Name));
```

Comment: Will it effect on performace? And is there any approach ingnore in all tipes exept few?

Comment: @Anton You cannot simply ignore types here, because entities have properties on their own. As for performance, as far as I know, entity model is build once per app domain, so it can increase startup performance at max.

Comment: Anything for EF5? I'm maintaining a legacy project that uses EF5. `Types` is not exposed in EF5.